# No Persistence provider for EntityManager

Tags: mysql, jpa, eclipselink, java-ee-7

I am trying to make java ee application using jax-rs and jpa. For JPA implementation i am using eclipselink.

here is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ClientManagement</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/javax.persistence -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

persistance.xml in directory main/resources/META-INF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="abc">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.example.MyGreeting</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/greeting"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Implemented resource class

```
@Path("user")
public class UserResource {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getResult() {
        EntityManagerFactory emf;
        EntityManager em;

        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("abc");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();


        MyGreeting g = new MyGreeting();
        g.setId(1);
        g.setName("hello, createAndRead");
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(g);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        MyGreeting g2 = em.find(MyGreeting.class, g.getId());
        System.out.println("g2 = " + g2.getName());
        return "hello  test world java";
    }
}
```

Here is the log of server

```
StandardWrapperValve[com.example.MyApplication]: Servlet.service() for servlet com.example.MyApplication threw exception
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named abc
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at com.example.UserResource.getResult(UserResource.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:309)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:460)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:334)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]
```

MyGreeting.class

```
@Entity
public class MyGreeting {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Greeting greeting = (Greeting) o;

        if (id != greeting.id) return false;
        if (name != null ? !name.equals(greeting.name) : greeting.name != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id;
        result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is called `persistence.xml` not `persistance.xml`